# Java BufferedWriter exporting file/directory listing .replaceAll alternative?

Tags: java, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter, replaceall

Exporting a given directory and file list to a file using BufferedWriter on Java8 (Eclipse IDE). This is working fine.

**Some files have special characters** like "[", "]" or extensions such as ".zip" that I wish to strip out when saving my file. Tried .replaceALL but getting stuck with how to make this work. Any suggestions please?

```
public static void getDirectoryList() throws IOException
{
String path = "C:\\Users\\";
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
File file = new File("DirectoryList.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getName());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
for (File f : listOfFiles) {

        // .replaceALL wants to be cast. Is there an alternative to 
        // .replaceAll when listing out a file listing to file.
        // Or, am I doing something silly....
        f = f.replaceAll(".zip", "");
        bw.write(f.getName());
        bw.newLine();
    }
bw.close();
}
```

**Example of Current text file output:**

[name1].doc      <-trying to remove "[" and "]" when saving name to file.

filename.zip     <-trying to remove ".zip" when saving name to file.

directoryname1

directoryname2

*(Original file and directory names remain, only the results save to the file are being changed.)*

**Required text file output**

name1.doc

filename

directoryname1

directoryname2

Comment: `File` has no `replaceAll` method. Get the file name first, and use `replaceAll` on that. Please check the apidoc before asking a question like this.

Comment: Thanks Mark, only started learning coding recently, wouldn't currently know where to look for what you're suggesting. It'll come as my knowledge grows.

Comment: You start with the [Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), and look for the classes you use. Also if you use an IDE, you have a lot of support in that (code completion, access to javadoc directly from your code), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceAll` isn't a method of `File`, it's a method of `String`.

```
for(File f : listOfFiles) {
     String fileName = f.getName();
     fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\.zip", "");
     fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\[", "");
     fileName = fileName.replaceAll("]", "");

     bw.write(fileName);
     bw.newLine();
}
```

Also notice that when I use `replaceAll` to remove '.zip' from the filename the `.` must be escaped. That's because the first parameter of `replaceAll` is a regex and dot `.` is a special character. The same for `[`.

There is a more compact way to do the same thing with a single regex

```
for(File f : new File("").listFiles()) {
     String fileName = f.getName();
     fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\.zip|\\[|]", "");

     bw.write(fileName);
     bw.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fllod2d. This solved my problem. Ticked solution :)